# Scanning through a hash and return a value if true

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

Based on my hash, I want to match it if it's in the string:

```
def conv
  str = "I only have one, two or maybe sixty"
  hash = {:one => 1, :two => 2, :six => 6, :sixty => 60 }
  str.match( Regexp.union( hash.keys.to_s ) )
end

puts conv # => <blank>
```

The above does not work but this only matches "one":

```
str.match( Regexp.union( hash[0].to_s ) )
```

**Edited:**

Any idea how to match "one", "two" and sixty in the string exactly?

If my string has "sixt" it return "6" and that should not happen based on @Cary's answer.

Comment: Change the operative line to `str.scan( Regexp.union(hash.keys.map(&:to_s) ) )`. `"one"` and `"two"` will be printed on successive lines.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That worked. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert each element of `hash.keys` to a string, rather than converting the array `hash.keys` to a string, and you should use [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) rather than [String#match](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-match). You may also need to play around with the regex until it returns everyhing you want and nothing you don't want.

Let's first look at your example:

```
str = "I only have one, two or maybe sixty"
hash = {:one => 1, :two => 2, :six => 6, :sixty => 60}
```

We might consider constructing the regex with word breaks (`\b`) before and after each word we wish to match:

```
r0 = Regexp.union(hash.keys.map { |k| /\b#{k.to_s}\b/ })
  #=> /(?-mix:\bone\b)|(?-mix:\btwo\b)|(?-mix:\bsix\b)|(?-mix:\bsixty\b)/

str.scan(r0)
  #=> ["one", "two", "sixty"]
```

Without the word breaks, `scan` would return `["one", "two", "six"]`, as `"sixty"` in `str` would match `"six"`. (Word breaks are zero-width. One before a string requires that the string be preceded by a non-word character or be at the beginning of the string. One after a string requires that the string be followed by a non-word character or be at the end of the string.)

Depending on your requirements, word breaks may not be sufficient or suitable. Suppose, for example (with `hash` above):

```
str = "I only have one, two, twenty-one or maybe sixty"
```

and we do not wish to match `"twenty-one"`. However,

```
str.scan(r0)
  #=> ["one", "two", "one", "sixty"]
```

One option would be to use a regex that demands that matches be preceded by whitespace or be at the beginning of the string, and be followed by whitespace or be at the end of the string:

```
r1 = Regexp.union(hash.keys.map { |k| /(?<=^|\s)#{k.to_s}(?=\s|$)/ })
str.scan(r1)
  #=> ["sixty"]
```

`(?<=^|\s)` is a *positive lookbehind*; `(?=\s|$)` is a *positive lookahead*.

Well, that avoided the match of `"twenty-one"` (good), but we no longer matched `"one"` or `"two"` (bad) because of the comma following each of those words in the string.

Perhaps the solution here is to first remove punctuation, which allows us to then apply either of the above regexes:

```
str.tr('.,?!:;-','')
  #=> "I only have one two twentyone or maybe sixty" 

str.tr('.,?!:;-','').scan(r0)
  #=> ["one", "two", "sixty"] 

str.tr('.,?!:;-','').scan(r1)
  #=> ["one", "two", "sixty"]
```

You may also want to change `/` at the end of the regex to `/i` to make the match insensitive to case.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1 [Historical note](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Type_cases) for readers who want to know why 'a' is called *lower case* and 'A' is called *upper case*.</sup>

Comment: Great. What happen if the hash had "six" and "sixty" and my string has "sixty". How to get the all others except six? Your answer does not seem to match exact values.